# Modify a variable inside another class and file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

*(Non-English native)*
This is tricky to explain. I have 2 windows, each one with their own class created by PyQt5, on 2 different .py files. I want to open the 2nd window from a button inside the first one, and then I want that 2nd window to destroy itself when closed. However, in order to do this, I believe I have to set a specific variable in the 1st window to None, but since that is instanced I can't find out how:

**First window in myfile.py**

```
class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.window_nuevocliente = None
        self.actionNuevo_Cliente.triggered.connect(self.open_secondwindow)

    def open_secondwindow(self):
        if self.window_nuevocliente is None:
            self.window_nuevocliente = addnewclient_logic.AddNewClientForm(self)
            self.window_nuevocliente.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.window_nuevocliente.show()

myapp = MainForm()
```

**Second window in addnewclient_logic.py**

```
import myfile

class AddNewClientForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_AddNewClient):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Do closing stuff
        event.accept()
        # Set the first class var window_nuevocliente back to None
        myfile.myapp.window_nuevocliente = None
```

And here is where I'm stuck:

That last line doesn't work. When I close the window, the DeleteOnClose will totally destroy the window, but the first window will still have it assigned on the `window_nuevocliente` var and so it fails to re-create it from scratch. If I instead omit the check if it's None, the window can be opened multiple times at the same time (and I don't want that).

Comment: Explain better and do not talk about files, talk about classes and instances. The files are only text, in programming we work with classes and instances.

Comment: I know, but my issue is that I can't seem to find the proper "pathing" to modify the variable `window_nuevocliente`of an instanced MainForm class (named myapp), from another different class. I tried `myfile.myapp.window_nuevocliente` but that path doesn't works. I specified the file names just to also request how to access to the full path of the variable in this situation.

Comment: I get distracted in the files that do not know what variable you want to modify, what class it is and what other class you describe. Please read the following to ask a better question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `myfile.myapp.window_nuevocliente = None`: myapp is not static variable, you must access it through an instance. try with `self.deleteLater()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it by adding the `destroyed` signal.

```
    def open_secondwindow(self):
        if self.window_nuevocliente is None:
            self.window_nuevocliente = addnewclient_logic.AddNewClientForm(self)
            self.window_nuevocliente.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
            self.window_nuevocliente.destroyed.connect(self.reset_nuevocliente)
        self.window_nuevocliente.show()

    def reset_nuevocliente(self):
        self.window_nuevocliente = None
```

I will accept a better solution, though :P

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the `window_nuevocliente` attribute like this:

*addnewclient_logic.py*:

```
class AddNewClientForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_AddNewClient):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

*myfile.py*:

```
from addnewclient_logic import AddNewClientForm

class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionNuevo_Cliente.triggered.connect(self.open_secondwindow)

    def open_secondwindow(self):
        window_nuevocliente = self.findChild(AddNewClientForm)
        if window_nuevocliente is None:
            window_nuevocliente = AddNewClientForm(self)
        window_nuevocliente.show()
```

The parent window will hold a reference to the child window until it deletes itself on close - at which point, it will also be removed from the parent's list of children.

Comment: I am trying to adapt my code to this but it always crashes when I open the window, close it and try to open it again.

Comment: @Saelyth. It works fine for me. But all I have to work with is the code in your question. I would guess that in your full code, there is an extra reference held somewhere to the child window, so it does not get deleted properly when it closes.